# How to limit the exception thrown in multi threaded environment

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-boot, spring-mvc

We have 2 classes A and B

In class A, we are calling the method of class B using thread simultaneously

An exception is thrown multiple times from class B. But we need to log the exception only once in DB

How to achieve this in java? Any ideas/tips are welcome

Example:

```
    public class A {
    public static void main(String...a){
        try{
            //......
            B b=new B();
            for(;;)
            b.method();
            //....
        }catch (Exception e){
            //DB insert logic here
        }
    }
}



class B {
        public void method() throws  Exception {
           // ....
            int i=1/0;
    
            throw new Exception();
            }
    }
```

Comment: Use a flag in catch block, default value is zero, when insert log in db in case of exception set in to one. And for the next exceptions check the flag.

Comment: Your example does not use threads, and it will only throw `Exception` once.  Please update the example so that it illustrates what you are really trying to do.